# C# Delegates - How Often Do You Use Them, And When?

Tags: c#, delegates

Delegates look like such a powerful language feature, but I've yet to find an opportunity to use them in anger (apart from in DALs I must say).

How often do you use them, and under what circumstances do you find them most useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funcs and Actions are newish "types" of delegates and I use them a lot with Linq and really other odd situations.  For Linq they are nice because personally I'd rather have a descriptive name than a lambda expression:

```
someList.Select(item => item.Name);
```

Where with a Func I can:

```
Func<Item, String> itemName = item => item.Name;
...
someList.Select(itemName);
```

It might be a line more, but there are times where I find myself repeating a certain lambda expressions a couple times in a class, so personally I think Funcs work well for that.

Another situation is a, for lack of a better term, Method Factory.  Basically it is a dictionary that holds a list of Actions as the value and say an Enum as the key:

```
Dictionary<UserType, Action<User>> showControls;
showControls = new Dictionary<UserType, Action<User>>();

showControls.Add(SomeEnum.Admin, setControlsForAdmin);
showControls.Add(SomeEnum.Normal, setControlsForNormalUser);
showControls.Add(SomeEnum.Unregistered, setControlsForUnregisteredUser);
```

And then I have the methods themselves written out somewhere else on the page.  And use would be:

```
showControls[user.UserType]();
```

Or maybe you want to pass the method itself to another:

```
Action<User> neededMethod;

neededMethod = showControls[user.UserType];

SomeMethod(neededMethod);
```

I'm sure there are much better uses for delegates, but these are useful.

Answer (score 6):

I use C# Delegate the most of time with Event.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e, string otherParameterIWant);
//...Inside the class
public event MyDelegate myEvent;
//...Inside a method
if (myEvent != null)
    myEvent(this, new EventArgs(), "Test for SO");
```

Answer (score 4):

I use them for event handlers, callbacks, and predicates to name a few. If you've programmed in C++, you can think of them as function pointers and I think some of their uses become immediately apparent.

Answer (score 3):

I especially like delegates when you have to change out one thing in the middle of boilerplate code:

```
public delegate bool ItemFilterDelegate(MyItem item);

public IEnumerable<MyItem> FilterItems(ItemFilterDelegate filter)
{
    var result = new List<MyItem>();

    foreach(MyItem item in AllItems)
    {
        if(filter(item))
            result.Add(item);
    }

    return item;
}    

public IEnumerable<MyItem> FilterByName(string name)
{
    return FilterItems(item => item.Name == name);
}
```

They are ALSO used heavily in this way with LINQ.

Comment: As a side note, the ItemFilterDelegate can be completely replaced with Func<MyItem, bool> if you want, but I think calling it out might be a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Events, Predicate Searches, Sometimes inline functionality.. they come in useful in a ton of scenarious..

List.ForEach(delegate...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, with lambda expression added in C#3, they become much easier to use, as the messy parts are hidden.

```
myList.Sort(a=> a.LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use them the most for callbacks. Instead of objects for callback methods (using interfaces), I can wrap a method in a delegate and pass that on.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use them all the time as Daok says for events, until I learned that you can use built-in handlers for most common events (common for what I do, at least).  Now I usually use them as callback handlers for API interaction.